# How to get id of div, on click of button, inside it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have multiple panels and each panel have Add button in it:

```
<div id="panel1">
<input type="button" id="addbut" value="Add it"></input>
</div>
<div id="panel2">
<input type="button" id="addbut" value="Add it"></input>
</div>
<div id="panel3">
<input type="button" id="addbut" value="Add it"></input>
</div>
```

On click of button, i want to print id(or other attributes) of div in which this button is contained. In JQuery,

```
$("#addbut").click(function(){
 alert(ID of panel to which this button belong - this.?) <-- Want to achieve
});
```

If button in panel1 is clicked, then it should alert or consolelog id i.e panel1.

I hope the question is clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it like :

```
$("#addbut").click(function(){
 alert($(this).parent().attr('id')) <-- Want to achieve
});
```

You can also do it this way:

```
$("#addbut").click(function(){
  alert($(this).closest('div').attr('id'))
});
```

Also note that you should have unique `id` for each element. So use a `class` instead like `class="addbut"`, and the code will be

```
$(".addbut").click(function(){
  alert($(this).closest('div').attr('id')) //OR $(this).parent().attr('id')
});
```

Answer (score 4):

The div is the parent of the button so you can get the parentNode and its id

```js
$(".addbut").click(function() {
  alert(this.parentNode.id);
  console.log($(this).parent().attr('id'))
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="panel1">
  <input type="button" class="addbut" value="Add it" />
</div>
<div id="panel2">
  <input type="button" class="addbut" value="Add it" />
</div>
<div id="panel3">
  <input type="button" class="addbut" value="Add it" />
</div>
```

Also note that the ID of an element must be unique, so use a common class for all the buttons and use that to register the click handler.

Answer (score 2):

*ID* **must** be unique, so change `id` to `class`, like so

```js
$(".addbut").click(function(){
  alert($(this).parent().attr('id'));
  // $(this) - refers to button 
  // $(this).parent() returns parent element
  // .attr('id') return id attribute    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="panel1">
  <input type="button" class="addbut" value="Add it">
</div>

<div id="panel2">
  <input type="button" class="addbut" value="Add it">
</div>

<div id="panel3">
  <input type="button" class="addbut" value="Add it">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".addbut").click(function(){
alert($(this).parent().attr('id')); 
});


// this refers to the current element
// .parent() returns the nearest parent of a element<br>
// you can get any attribute using .attr() method on the required element
```